# How to put random number in array and showing this array in php

Tags: php

Recently I made a program to create 4 random numbers I want to put these numbers in an array but I did not echo the array's numbers :

my code is:

```
 <?php
    $numbers = array();
    function rand_num_generator() {
    return rand(1000,9999);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
    $number[i] = rand_num_generator();
    }
    echo $number[2];
?>
```

Here i am not able to access array using their index values.

Comment: why are you ignoring the PHP warnings? `i` must have generated one...

Comment: you are missing '$'  in  $number[i] = rand_num_generator();  so the asssignment will be $number[$i] = rand_num_generator();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `$` sign in front of the `i` inside `$number[i]` which must be used before a variable

```
$numbers = array();
function rand_num_generator() {
return rand(1000,9999);
}
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
$number[$i] = rand_num_generator();
echo $number[$i].'<br>';
}

//print_r($number);to see the whole array
```

Answer (score 2):

You only `echo` once: at `echo $number[i];`, `$i` is `4`, hence you only display the last random number.

You could loop on your array to echo each.

Answer (score 0):

Put your echo into loop. And you have some mistakes. Use that:

```
$numbers = array();
    function rand_num_generator() {
    return rand(1000,9999);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
   $number[$i] = rand_num_generator();
    echo $number[$i].'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To put something in an array I recommend to use [array_push](http://www.php.net/array_push)

```
<?php
$numbers = array();
function rand_num_generator() {
    return rand(1000,9999);
}

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
    array_push($numbers, rand_num_generator());
}
print_r($numbers); //Or use 'echo $numbers[0] . " " . $numbers[1]' etc etc
```

?>